# Unset data without losing event handler

Tags: jquery

having for example

```
<div>
 <a>anything....</a>
</div>
```

set event handler:

```
$("div a").click(.....)
```

while using later `$("div").html('')` event handler for `<div><a>` get lost.

Is there any way to do this job - clean content - and let handlers exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delegate the handler to something higher up the DOM, like the `<body>`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div a', function () {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .live():

```
$("div a").live("click", function(){ 
    alert("Still exists"); 
});
```

Which according to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is to:

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/3zKfa/).

Comment: From jQuery docs: *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."*

Answer (score 0):

Would [jQuery.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) be of any use? Give your link a reference (class, ID) and you should preserve its behaviour.